# Running code based on application platform

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, uwp, cross-platform

Trying to make a cross-platform application library that will be able to work on UWP, Winforms, Wpf, Android and iOS.

Using NetStandard2.0

I've been using Xamarin Forms to test the library because of the cross-platform option but something I want to do is to get hardware information and emulate the devices such as Audio output.

I can't find a way that works across all platforms/devices only ones that target specific. And I can't find a way to run specific code or use a specific library based on the platform that is running.

Targeting multiple frameworks don't work because they cause errors in all the other files.
Tried creating separate libraries that are specifically targeting a platform like UWP, Android and iOS separately but when referencing them, I get a not supported errors:

```
Project ****.UWP is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). 
Project ****.UWP supports: uap10.0.17763 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17763)
```

stuff like that and for each project (UWP, Android and iOS)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

> Targeting multiple frameworks don't work because they cause errors in all the other files. Tried creating separate libraries that are specifically targeting a platform like UWP,

The platform specific code can't be used into share library directly. for calling native api for each platforms. the better way is using `DependencyService` to approach. And here is [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) that you could refer to.

And the other way is using [Conditional Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation#conditional-compilation)

For example

```
public static string DatabaseFilePath
{
    get
    {
        var filename = "TodoDatabase.db3";
#if SILVERLIGHT
        // Windows Phone 8
        var path = filename;
#else

#if __ANDROID__
        string libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
#else
#if __IOS__
        // we need to put in /Library/ on iOS5.1 to meet Apple's iCloud terms
        // (they don't want non-user-generated data in Documents)
        string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
        string libraryPath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, "..", "Library");
#else
        // UWP
        string libraryPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
#endif
#endif
        var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, filename);
#endif
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, just tried the Conditional Compilation. It didn't work, nothing was returned when doing #if WINDOWS_UWP return "test"; #endif    nothing was returned, the code didn't even fire despite being called. I've also got a way to tell what platform is running now but its not like that.   DependencyService documentation doesn't completely explain how to set it up, it shows small snippets but not saying you need to create new libraries or files or anything to set it up.

Comment: Can you share your code for testing, and DependencyService has complete document. and if also provide code [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/dependencyservice/).